# Identifying json & jquery in this specific example?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, wcf

I creates some charts using `Kendo UI`. These charts get the data from a `wcf service` I created in `asp.net`.

Even though I created the chart and the underlying service, I'm still unsure what code's `json` and what code's `jquery`.

Any help identifying these will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

```
var WebService = "/ServiceDash.svc/";

function createPenetrationPieChart(Tech) {
    var url = WebService + "GetPenetration?";
    switch (Tech) {
        case "Sales1":
            url = url + "GroupId=Sales&State=1";
            break;
        case "Sales2":
            url = url + "GroupId=Sales&State=2";
            break;
        case "Sales3":
            url = url + "GroupId=Sales&State=3";
            break;
    }

    $("#" + Tech).kendoChart({
        legend: {
            visible: false
        },
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: url,
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            }
        },
        chartArea: {
            margin: 0,
            height: 150 /* add this option */
        },
        series: [{
            type: "donut",
            field: "Penetration"
        }],
        seriesColors: ["#0C5885", "#000000"],
        tooltip: {
            visible: true
            //template: "${ value }%"
        }
    });
}

function FillCharts() {
    createSitePenetrationPieChart("Sales1");
}

$(document).ready(FillCharts);
$(document).bind("kendo:skinChange", FillCharts);
```

Comment: json = data, jquery = application

Comment: So if I'm looking for charts that can be populated by a WCF service method call, should I search "charts json" or "charts jquery"?

Comment: You'd be looking for a jquery chart that can handle json data.  It's optional if you actually want a jquery chart as you might just need an html5 chart - so if that's not a requirement, then look for charts that can handle a json data source (most likely any written in the last 5 years will handle json).

Comment: I understand it's a simple question, but please let me know why my question was downvoted so that I can improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can identify jQuery by the dollar sign $. jQuery is mainly used to manipulate DOM elements.  JSON is a way to package data.  So in your specific example,

```
$('#' + Tech).kendoChart({...})
```

identifies a DOM element.  everything inside that is JSON.

Comment: Thanks. So if I'm  looking for charts that can be populated by a WCF service method call, should I search "charts json" or "charts jquery"?